# Get width of a resized image after UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have my UIImageView and I put an image into it that I resize like this:

```
UIImageView *attachmentImageNew = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.5, 6.5, 245, 134)];
attachmentImageNew.image = actualImage;
attachmentImageNew.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
attachmentImageNew.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I tried getting the width of the resized picture in my `UIImageView` by doing this:

```
NSLog(@"Size of pic is %f", attachmentImageNew.image.size.width);
```

But it actually returns me the width of the original picture. Any ideas on how do I get the frame of the picture that I see on screen?

**EDIT:** Here's how my `UIImageView` looks, red area is its `backgroundColor`

[image]

Comment: Just check update in my answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't know is there more clear solution, but this works:

```
float widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / imageView.image.size.width;
float heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / imageView.image.size.height;
float scale = MIN(widthRatio, heightRatio);
float imageWidth = scale * imageView.image.size.width;
float imageHeight = scale * imageView.image.size.height;
```

Comment: For those who are wondering what MIN() function is, I believe you can replace with this line of code:   float scale = widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

Comment: Copy paste function in swift, related to @Mikhail's answer:
    `func getScaledSizeOfImage(image: UIImage, toSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var widthRatio = toSize.width/image.size.width
        var heightRatio = toSize.height/image.size.height
        var scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        var imageWidth = scale*image.size.width
        var imageHeight = scale*image.size.height
        return CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight)
    }`

Comment: Swift 3.0 Version: let widthRatio = imageView.bounds.size.width / (imageView.image?.size.width)!
        let heightRatio = imageView.bounds.size.height / (imageView.image?.size.height)!
        let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
        let imageWidth = scale * (imageView.image?.size.width)!
        let imageHeight = scale * (imageView.image?.size.height)!

Answer (score 1):

A solution in Swift:

```
let currentHeight = imageView.bounds.size.height
let currentWidth = imageView.bounds.size.width
let newWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let newHeight = (newWidth * currentHeight) / currentWidth

println(newHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has the reference of your original image, so always gives the same dimensions as of original image.

To get the dimensions of new image you have to check aspect ratio. I have derived a formula for my need using different images of different size using Preview that how it resizes image according to its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's Documentation for **[UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW159)**

> It Scales the **content** (In your case actualImage) to fit the size of the **view** (In your case attachmentImageNew) by maintaining the
>   aspect ratio.

That means your image size ( after the scaling ) should be same as your `UIImageView`.

**UPDATE :**

One new Suggestion to you if you don't want to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` and if you can fix the size of `scaledImage` then you can use below code to scale the image for fix newSize and then you can use the width to your code.

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(100.0,50.0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case:

```
float yourScaledImageWitdh =  attachmentImageNew.frame.size.height *  attachmentImageNew.image.size.width / attachmentImageNew.image.size.height
NSLog(@"width of resized pic is %f", yourScaledImageWitdh);
```

but you should also check, before, the original image proportion vs the imageView proportion, my line of code is good just in case the red area is added horizontally, not in case your original image proportion is wider than the imageView frame proportion

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 2**, you can use this code snippet to align an **aspectFitted** image to the **bottom** of the **screen** (sampled from earlier answers to this question -> thanks to you, guys)

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = CGFloat(screenSize.width)
let screenHeight = CGFloat(screenSize.height)

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - (imageView.image?.size.height)! , screenWidth, (imageView.image?.size.height)!)

let newSize:CGSize = getScaledSizeOfImage(imageView.image!, toSize: self.view.frame.size)

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - (newSize.height) , screenWidth, newSize.height)

func getScaledSizeOfImage(image: UIImage, toSize: CGSize) -> CGSize       
{
    let widthRatio = toSize.width/image.size.width
    let heightRatio = toSize.height/image.size.height
    let scale = min(widthRatio, heightRatio)
    let imageWidth = scale*image.size.width
    let imageHeight = scale*image.size.height
    return CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight)
}
```