# How to resize a GMSMarker icon in Google Maps for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK in xCode and trying to scale a marker icon to make it bigger on the mapView.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
marker.icon.scale = 3.0f;
```

But it gives me a:

> assignment to readonly property error

Obviously since it's readonly, I cannot write to it.

Therefore, is there an alternative to be able to resize or scale my marker icon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to change the size of your icon which is an UIImage programmatically, you can implement a custom method to change your UIImage to your desired scale.

You can try the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650811/4195406).

After you implement that method in your code, you can do the following to change your icon (because marker.icon is writable):

```
marker.icon = [self image:marker.icon scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(3.0f, 3.0f)];
```

Answer (score 3):

you can covert the image to NSData

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

and then use UIImage API method imageWithData:scale: , you can change your icon to any scale you want:

```
marker.icon = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData scale:2.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
```

then assign it to marker

```
marker.iconView = imageView;
```